Problem with cascade persist in Hibernate with 3 entities
I have 3 entities: Proyectos (projects), Plantillas (templates) and paginas (Pages).
I am trying to do mapping with bidirectional relationships and I persist a new Project and I would like persist child entities in cascade.
Entity Proyecto:
@Entity
@Table(name = "P_PROYECTOS")
public class Proyecto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_PROYECTO")
    private Integer idProyecto;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proyecto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Plantilla> plantillas;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proyecto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Pagina> paginas;

Entity Plantilla:
@Entity
@Table(name = "P_PLANTILLAS")
public class Plantilla implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "idProyecto", column = @Column(name = "ID_PROYECTO", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "idPlantilla", column = @Column(name = "ID_PLANTILLA", nullable = false)) })
    private PlantillaID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("idProyecto")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROYECTO", referencedColumnName = "ID_PROYECTO", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Proyecto proyecto;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plantilla", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Pagina> paginas;

Entity Pagina:
@Entity
@Table(name = "P_PAGINAS")
public class Pagina implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_PAGINA")
    private Integer idPagina;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROYECTO", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Proyecto proyecto;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROYECTO", referencedColumnName = "ID_PROYECTO", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PLANTILLA", referencedColumnName = "ID_PLANTILLA", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Plantilla plantilla;    
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_PROYECTO", nullable = false)
    private Integer idProyecto;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_PLANTILLA", nullable = false)
    private Integer idPlantilla;

Here an example to test the problem:
    Proyecto p=new Proyecto();
    p.setNombre("Proyecto prueba");
    projectService.probarGuardado(p);
    
    Plantilla pl=new Plantilla(p.getIdProyecto(), 1);
    pl.setProyecto(p);
    p.getPlantillas().add(pl);
    
    Pagina pag=new Pagina();
    pag.setIdProyecto(p.getIdProyecto());
    pag.setProyecto(p);
    pag.setIdPlantilla(1);
    pag.setPlantilla(pl);
    pl.getPaginas().add(pag);       
    p.getPaginas().add(pag);    <--- (*)    
    
    projectService.probarGuardado(p);   

Where probarGuardado does:
@Transactional
public void probarGuardado(Proyecto p) {       
    proyectoRepo.save(p);
}

Here debug output:
2024-05-04T21:52:33,320 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-6] o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger: insert into DB.P_PROYECTOS (NOMBRE) values (?)
2024-05-04T21:52:37,503 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-6] o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger: select proyecto0_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO1_53_1_, proyecto0_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE2_53_1_, paginas1_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO3_51_3_, paginas1_.ID_PAGINA as ID_PAGINA1_51_3_, paginas1_.ID_PAGINA as ID_PAGINA1_51_0_, paginas1_.ID_PLANTILLA as ID_PLANTILLA2_51_0_, paginas1_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO3_51_0_ from DB.P_PROYECTOS proyecto0_ left outer join DB.P_PAGINAS paginas1_ on proyecto0_.ID_PROYECTO=paginas1_.ID_PROYECTO where proyecto0_.ID_PROYECTO=?
2024-05-04T21:52:37,556 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-6] o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger: insert into DB.P_PAGINAS (ID_PLANTILLA, ID_PROYECTO) values (?, ?)2024-05-04T21:52:37,565 WARN  [http-nio-80-exec-6] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
2024-05-04T21:52:37,566 ERROR [http-nio-80-exec-6] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper: ORA-02291: restricción de integridad (DB.P_PAGINAS_P_PLANTILLAS_FK) violada - clave principal no encontrada

If I comment the line with the asterisk mark, all end fine and the persist order is the correct, persisting plantilla (template) before persists pagina (page):
2024-05-04T22:12:21,555 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-5] o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger: insert into DB.P_PROYECTOS (NOMBRE) values (?)
2024-05-04T22:12:24,204 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-5] o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger: select proyecto0_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO1_53_1_, proyecto0_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE2_53_1_, paginas1_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO3_51_3_, paginas1_.ID_PAGINA as ID_PAGINA1_51_3_, paginas1_.ID_PAGINA as ID_PAGINA1_51_0_, paginas1_.ID_PLANTILLA as ID_PLANTILLA2_51_0_, paginas1_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO3_51_0_ from DB.P_PROYECTOS proyecto0_ left outer join DB.P_PAGINAS paginas1_ on proyecto0_.ID_PROYECTO=paginas1_.ID_PROYECTO where proyecto0_.ID_PROYECTO=?
2024-05-04T22:12:24,214 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-5] o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger: select plantilla0_.ID_PLANTILLA as ID_PLANTILLA1_52_1_, plantilla0_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO2_52_1_, paginas1_.ID_PLANTILLA as ID_PLANTILLA2_51_3_, paginas1_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO3_51_3_, paginas1_.ID_PAGINA as ID_PAGINA1_51_3_, paginas1_.ID_PAGINA as ID_PAGINA1_51_0_, paginas1_.ID_PLANTILLA as ID_PLANTILLA2_51_0_, paginas1_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO3_51_0_ from DB.P_PLANTILLAS plantilla0_ left outer join DB.P_PAGINAS paginas1_ on plantilla0_.ID_PLANTILLA=paginas1_.ID_PLANTILLA and plantilla0_.ID_PROYECTO=paginas1_.ID_PROYECTO where plantilla0_.ID_PLANTILLA=? and plantilla0_.ID_PROYECTO=?
2024-05-04T22:12:24,236 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-5] o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger: insert into DB.P_PLANTILLAS (ID_PLANTILLA, ID_PROYECTO) values (?, ?)
2024-05-04T22:12:24,303 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-5] o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger: insert into DB.P_PAGINAS (ID_PLANTILLA, ID_PROYECTO) values (?, ?)
2024-05-04T22:12:24,324 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-5] o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger: select plantillas0_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO2_52_0_, plantillas0_.ID_PLANTILLA as ID_PLANTILLA1_52_0_, plantillas0_.ID_PLANTILLA as ID_PLANTILLA1_52_1_, plantillas0_.ID_PROYECTO as ID_PROYECTO2_52_1_ from DB.P_PLANTILLAS plantillas0_ where plantillas0_.ID_PROYECTO=?

Where is the problem? why hibernate does not persist the entities in the correct order? What am I doing wrong?
